# How could I make a giant pc in dnd 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, monsters, homebrew

I really would like to make a giant character for a 4e campaign, and if anyone could help me make some character profiles for each of the types of giants I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Here's some interesting discussion on why some people thing a Giant (large-sized) PC is a bad idea: http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Talk:Hill_Giant_%284e_Race%29

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the advantages and disadvantages of allowing a player to play a large creature?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9163/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-allowing-a-player-to-play-a-large-c)

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comments on the original question, Large sized creatures are not officially sanctioned as valid characters by WotC.

But, we Old School DMs try stuff like anyway - because it's fun. So here's the start of a possible home-brew variant, addressing some of the concerns raised on the thread: [What are the advantages and disadvantages of allowing a player to play a large creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9163/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-allowing-a-player-to-play-a-large-c)

I imagine you want to play a Giant for the extra die of damage. So be it. That's the primary advantage - but let's make it pretty much the only advantage, primarily offset by your size requirement: 2x2x2"

We've still got to fix the biggest balance problem raised by your size: `Close Burst/Aura` diameter

Suggested fix: Chose one of your current squares as the origin for the burst effect. `Burst/Aura 1` will then only hit your 4 squares plus 5 more - not the usual 9.  This specifically puts a cap on your number of adjacent enemies effected by powers like Defender Aura.

This is similar to the effects for `Mounted Combat`[<sup>ddi</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=582):

> ***Space***: .... Whenever the rider uses an effect that has an origin square (such as a melee, a ranged, a close, or an area power), the rider first picks where that square is located in the mount’s space, and the effect uses that origin square (the rider still shares the mount’s space for the purpose of triggering effects, such as opportunity attacks). For instance, if a Medium rider uses a close burst attack power, the rider chooses a single square within the mount’s space, and the burst emanates from that square.

In short, any *diameter* effect on one of your powers that would be increased as a result of your size, should be so modified. You lose 3 squares of effect in exchange for and extra damage die and other cool "I'm a Giant powers."

Comment: I'd like to expand this post with alternative design responses to any other critical concerns raised by the 4e players here. I'm thinking that homebrew is allowed here - not only official WotC cannon.

Comment: Good solution on the burst/aura problem, it's similar to what you do with mounts so that's a great start. (pick an origin square on your mount)

Comment: The damage is still an issue, I think. Any race with a strength boost and the ability to use larger weapons makes a hideously effective ranger. Or any multi-attacker really, but rangers are the champions in that department.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I'm cool with extra damage being the only real advantage. The general idea here is the negatives should equal out the extra damage. Any thoughts on other disadvantages? In the end, the DM always has to tune the encounters to match the party threat - so a few more monster hit-points or minions (wasting all the damage) and all is well again.  wax eagle: Great catch - modified post to reflect.

Comment: Well, the problem with limiting areas and bursts... is that the race just won't take them. As much as it's against the policy of 4e, I think the best bet here is to impose an accuracy penalty to counteract the large+reach weapon to provide "Average" damage. And under no circumstances grant threatening reach.

Comment: The problem with the advantage/disadvantage system of race design (and the reason the devs dropped it in 4e, if I recall correctly) is that the player is always going to build to maximize the impact of the advantages and minimize the impact of the disadvantages. I could see giving larger weapons in place of one of the stat bumps, and larger close bursts (but NOT auras) in place of the other stat bump, since those don't synergize all that well (weapon-based close bursts are fairly rare). I don't think anything could balance larger auras or threatening reach.

Comment: Great feedback @BrianBallsun-Stanton and Oblivious Sage... Threatening Reach should definitely be added to the "problem" list and resolved. Since this is a race, changing the stat-bumps is a great idea...